# Javascript get value from an object with the name contains special charactor

Tags: javascript

This is my object `abcd`; This object contains some variables such the names: `@promo`, `@size`, `@color`, `@value` etc. so how could I print these?

I have use `alert(abcd.{"@value"})` but this is showing me an error. So how could I get the value of the variable?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to access an object's property: `obj.key` and `obj["key"]`. The latter allows you to use any value or variable, which is what you want here.

Therefore, you should use `abcd["@value"]`.